# Make template from saga: wrappe part of saga in function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I need make like saga template  - wrapp part some of saga in function. I do it because many of my sagas have a similar structure and I try to decompose this code. Don't pay attention on details please, just give me please general view. I have problem with call my template like function

I would like make from like this:

```
function* signInSaga({ payload: { email, password } }) {
  const signUpBodyRequest = {
    'email': email,
    'password': password,
  };

  try {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('email', email);
    formData.append('password', password);
    yield put(actions.requestSignIn());
    const data = yield call(() => {
      return fetch('test.url/sign_in', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
      }).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      });
    });
    if (data.token) {
      yield put(actions.requestSignInSuccess(data));
    } else {
      yield put(actions.requestSignInError());
    }
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(actions.requestSignInError());
  }
}
```

To like this:

```
 function* signInSaga({ payload: { email, password } }) {
  const signInBodyRequest = {
    'email': email,
    'password': password
  };
  sagaTemplate(
    'test.url/sign_in',
    actions.requestSignIn,
    actions.requestSignInSuccess,
    actions.requestSignInError,
    'POST',
    signInBodyRequest
  );
}
```

Now my saga template look next way:

```
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';

export function* sagaTemplate(url, request, requestSucces, requestError, method, bodyRequest) {
  try {
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(bodyRequest)) {
      formData.append(key, value);
    }
    yield put(request());
    const data = yield call(() => {
      return fetch(url, {
        method: method,
        body: formData
      }).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      });
    });
    if (data.token) {
      yield put(requestSucces(data));
    } else {
      yield put(requestError());
    }
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(requestError());
  }
}
```

How correctly call my function template in saga?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things, one you will use the saga effect `call`, which takes the function you want to call, followed by a comma separated list of arguments it takes.

```
yield call(sagaTemplate, arguments, in, their, correct, order);
```

Second, I would suggest sending an object, which can be destructured, which contains all of your arguments, keeping the likelihood of mixing up argument orders to zero.